# No consigo escribir con cursiva y negrita a la vez en jTextPane - Java Swing

Tags: java-swing

Hola estoy haciendo un procesador de textos en Java y estuve programando los botones de Cursiva y Negrita. Si aplico los estilos a texto que he seleccionado funciona pero al intentar escribir no me van a la vez. Para ello utilizo un AttributeSet donde defino los atributos que voy añadiendo sea Bold, Italic... pienso que igual se inicializa todo el rato el AttributeSet por eso nunca consigo que estén las dos a la vez pero es que moví y la hice variable global pero nada... ayuda por favor

Botón cursiva:

```
private void jRadioButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) jTextPane1.getDocument();
    
    if (jRadioButton2.isEnabled()) {
        int selectionEnd = jTextPane1.getSelectionEnd();
        int selectionStart = jTextPane1.getSelectionStart();
        if (selectionStart == selectionEnd) {
            SimpleAttributeSet attributeSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setItalic(attributeSet, true);
            jTextPane1.setCharacterAttributes(attributeSet, true);
        }else{
            Element element = doc.getCharacterElement(selectionStart);
            AttributeSet as = element.getAttributes();
            MutableAttributeSet asNew = new SimpleAttributeSet(as.copyAttributes());
            StyleConstants.setItalic(asNew, !StyleConstants.isItalic(as));
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(selectionStart, jTextPane1.getSelectedText().length(), asNew, true);
            estilo_seleccionado = doc.getFont(as).getStyle();
        }
        es_cursiva = true;
    } else if (!jRadioButton2.isEnabled()) {
        int selectionEnd = jTextPane1.getSelectionEnd();
        int selectionStart = jTextPane1.getSelectionStart();
        if (selectionStart == selectionEnd) {
            SimpleAttributeSet attributeSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setItalic(attributeSet, false);
            jTextPane1.setCharacterAttributes(attributeSet, false);
        }else{
        Element element = doc.getCharacterElement(selectionStart);
        AttributeSet as = element.getAttributes();
        MutableAttributeSet asNew = new SimpleAttributeSet(as.copyAttributes());
        StyleConstants.setItalic(asNew, !StyleConstants.isItalic(as));
        doc.setCharacterAttributes(selectionStart, jTextPane1.getSelectedText().length(), asNew, false);
        estilo_seleccionado = doc.getFont(as).getStyle();
        }
        es_cursiva = false;
    }
}
```

Botón negrita:

```
private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) jTextPane1.getDocument();
     
    if (jRadioButton1.isEnabled()) {
        int selectionEnd = jTextPane1.getSelectionEnd();
        int selectionStart = jTextPane1.getSelectionStart();
        if (selectionStart == selectionEnd) {
            SimpleAttributeSet attributeSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setBold(attributeSet, true);
            jTextPane1.setCharacterAttributes(attributeSet, true); 
        }else{
        Element element = doc.getCharacterElement(selectionStart);
        AttributeSet as = element.getAttributes();
        MutableAttributeSet asNew = new SimpleAttributeSet(as.copyAttributes());
        StyleConstants.setBold(asNew, !StyleConstants.isBold(as));
        doc.setCharacterAttributes(selectionStart, jTextPane1.getSelectedText().length(), asNew, true);
        estilo_seleccionado = doc.getFont(as).getStyle();
        }
        es_negrita = true;
    } else if (!jRadioButton1.isEnabled()) {
        int selectionEnd = jTextPane1.getSelectionEnd();
        int selectionStart = jTextPane1.getSelectionStart();
        if (selectionStart == selectionEnd) {
            SimpleAttributeSet attributeSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setBold(attributeSet, false);
            jTextPane1.setCharacterAttributes(attributeSet, false);
        }else{
        Element element = doc.getCharacterElement(selectionStart);
        AttributeSet as = element.getAttributes();
        MutableAttributeSet asNew = new SimpleAttributeSet(as.copyAttributes());
        StyleConstants.setBold(asNew, !StyleConstants.isBold(as));
        doc.setCharacterAttributes(selectionStart, jTextPane1.getSelectedText().length(), asNew, false);
        estilo_seleccionado = doc.getFont(as).getStyle();
        }
        es_negrita = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podrías comprobar en cada botón el estado de `es_cursiva` y `es_negrita`. No veo que estés usando esas variables en otro sitio. Por ejemplo, si estás en el código del botón de cursiva, podrías comprobar si `es_negrita` está a `true` y, si lo está, podrías ejecutar `setItalic` y `setBold` en el mismo botón.